# unable to connect wired and wireless

Tags: wireless, wired

I'm able to connect through a tethered connection but not through Ethernet or a external wireless adapter. The network shows up on the network panel however get disconnected.

things already done :

1. followed ["Wired Network Disconnected" even when connected- no ethernet connection possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398747) - unable to change networkmanager.config
2. start, stop, restart network services
3. added a new a network connection
4. Tried to install the driver - unable to install tar ball using make and install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the below links :

[Unable to connect to detected wireless network while connects to wired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73730)

["Wired Network Disconnected" even when connected- no ethernet connection possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398747)

[Ubuntu 17.04 connected to wifi but can't browse internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907763)

Was able to enable wired and wifi connection

Using Lubuntu 17.04, hence used leafpad instead of gedit
Also if you do not have permissions to make changes using GUI, use terminal
this might be of disabling prompt for credentials on log in

Thanks all for help